# Power cut before closing ofstream c++

Tags: c++, file

I'm using ofstream in c++. It's possible data corruption if all data are written but power cut before calling close() ?

Note that, ofstream destructor has not yet been called at the time of the power cut

Help me to understand please.

**Edit**

Example

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
int main()
{
    std::ofstream fos("t.bin", std::ios::binary);
    int data = 1;
    fos.write((char*)&data, sizeof(data));
    //--> power cut when execution is here <--
    fos.close();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Power off means no software is running anymore (immediately), so how would you imagine destructors being called??

Comment: Flushing the IO buffers after the writes might help (but I doubt that you can get any guarantee with a power cut).

Comment: Everything is possible when everything stops working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several layers involved when writing data to disk:

1. `std::ofstream` will keep data in memory until you call `flush()` or `close()` it.
2. Your OS might keep the written data in memory until it gets around to telling the disk to write bytes. You can call `fdatasync()` or `fsync()` to ensure at least it is committed by the OS.
3. Finally, your disk probably also has a small buffer area for disk I/O commands. It will eventually get around to writing it to disk, but this mechanism would allow batching multiple writes to the same area in one operation.

Even if you do everything right, there is still a very tiny window where data is sitting in the disk buffer and not written to disk yet. This is why enterprise-grade disks have a small battery to ensure all queued writes go through even when power is cut.

Comment: Additionally, there are filesystem metadata changes that have to be written to disk (e.g. if the file becomes longer because of the write). A combination of  journaling filesystem and correct use of write barriers can prevent data loss. However, the C++ program writer usually has no control over these. If the data is important, call .flush(), and then call fsync(...). .close() doesn't matter (but.it calls .flush() for you, which matters).